# How do i select element in a list present in an un-ordered list using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

this the website I am dealing with https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/ann.html?curpg=1&annflag=1&dt=20211021&dur=P&dtto=20211027&cat=Insider%20Trading%20/%20SAST&scrip=&anntype=A
Here I am able to send the code for the "security name" but in-order to submit it I need to click the dropdown element that comes after giving the security name. How do I achieve this with selenium. I used the code below and its not working(StaleElementReferenceException)

```
security_name = driver.find_element_by_id("scripsearchtxtbx")
security_name.send_keys('INE350H01032')
sec_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ulSearchQuote2"]/li')
sec_click.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

This can *also* be accomplished using the **Keys Library** within Selenium. Selenium Keys **not only sends input statements** like strings, but it can **also send commands** such as escape, tab, or in this case enter. Your updated code should look as follows:

```
security_name = driver.find_element_by_id("scripsearchtxtbx")
security_name.send_keys('INE350H01032')
security_name.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sec_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ulSearchQuote2"]/li')
sec_click.click()
```

These are called *special keys*. For more examples and more information on this, see [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/special-keys-in-selenium-python/)

Answer (score 0):

you can paly with Xpath:

```
security_name = driver.find_element_by_id("scripsearchtxtbx")
security_name.send_keys('INE350H01032')
sec_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@id='ulSearchQuote2']/li//strong[text()='INE350H01032']")
sec_click.click()
same -->("//ul[@id='ulSearchQuote2']//strong[text()='INE350H01032']")
```

you can check more about xpath here: [xpath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).